# How is is_standard_layout implemented?

Tags: c++11, type-traits

In general one can implement typical `type_traits` using template techniques.

However I didn't imagine how `std::is_standard_layout` could be implemented in these terms. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_standard_layout

When I checked the `gcc` standard library, I found that it is implemented in terms of `__is_standard_layout(T)` which I could not find defined anywhere else. Is this a compiler magic function?

**Would it be possible to implement `std::is_standard_layout` explicitly?**

For example one of the conditions is that it inherits from a single class.
That seems to be impossible to determine at compile time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, `std::is_standard_layout` is not something you can implement without compiler intrinsics. As you've correctly pointed out, it needs more information than the C++ type system can express.